# symfony2 doctrine insert entity datetime wrong format for mysql

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, datetime, doctrine-orm

I am trying to port a project from mssql to mysql, used MySQL Workbench to port database - everything went well. When trying to insert data I get SQLSTATE[22007]: Invalid datetime format: 1292 Incorrect datetime value: '06/18/2015 14:49:22' for column 'x'. In the doctrine config Entityname.orm.yml I have:

```
x:
      type: datetime
      gedmo:
        timestampable:
          on: create
```

In entity class:

```
/**
 * @var datetime $x
 */
private $x;


/**
 * Set x
 *
 * @param datetime $x
 */
public function setX($x)
{
    $this->x= $x;
}
```

Code that causes the error:

```
$em = $this->container->get('doctrine')->getEntityManager();
$new_entity = new EntityName();
$new_entity->setX(new \DateTime());
$em->persist($new_entity );
$em->flush();
```

In _profiler I find :
INSERT INTO entity_name (x) VALUES (?) ({"1":{"date":"2015-06-18 14:49:22","timezone_type":3,"timezone":"Europe/Bucharest"}})

and after this the error.

This worked before when using the pdo_sqlsrv database_driver and the mssql database.

Edit: what worked - running set sql_mode=NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION; set global sql_mode=NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION; in mysql database - seems that the bad datetime formatting wasn't done by symfony. The error was caused by strict_trans_tables - SQL Mode changes the way MySQL executes SQL statements

Answer (score 1):

Better way do it on MySQL side? 
Just set your field like that:

```
date_x TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

After that:

```
$new_entity->setX(null);
```

You will get current date on MySQL side :)

Answer (score 0):

i think you should change the variable

```
/**
* @var \DateTime $x
*/
private $x;


/**
* Set x
*
* @param datetime $x
*/
public function setX(\DateTime $x)
{
   $this->x= $x;
}
```

as the call too

```
$em = $this->container->get('doctrine')->getEntityManager();
$new_entity = new EntityName();
$new_entity ->setX(new \DateTime());
$em->persist($new_entity );
$em->flush();
```

Comment: Sorry - I copied the wrong definition of variable. Edited